# Data management and callback functions with React native and React navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, callback

I am trying to code a mobile app to learn React Native. It's a very simple app to display current weather of predefined cities using API calls. Here you can see some screenshots of the app.

[HomeScreen View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCdKz.jpg),
[UserSettings View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE0SR.jpg)

Using react-navigation with a tab navigator, I would like to have one view (HomeScreen) which displays the results of the API calls (no problem here) and another one which can
edit the list of the cities (add or remove city).

My problem is to correctly manage the data.
I usually pass informations and callback functions between components with react but here it seems a little bit more complicated due to the use of react-navigation.

Using tabNavigator i can't use navigation options to pass informations between components so I use initialParams. But for callback functions i have some troubles like "Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state".

For this case, what would be the best practice to manage the data and callback functions?

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
export default function App() {
      const [cityList, setCityList]=useState(["city1","city2","city3"]);
    
      const addCityToList =function(cityName){
        setCityList((oldCityList)=>{return([...oldCityList,cityName])})
      }
    return(
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          {/**HomeScreen -> Display current weather for cities defined in UserSettings */}
          <Tab.Screen 
            name="Home" 
            component={HomeScreen} 
            initialParams={{ cityList:cityList}}/>
          
          {/*UserSettings -> View to add / remove cities */}
          <Tab.Screen 
            name="Settings" 
            component={UserSettings} 
            initialParams={
              { cityList:cityList, 
                addCityToList:addCityToList}
            } />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
      }
```

Comment: try using Context. This could be the best way to fill your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a global state using `Context` as follows.

```js
export const CityContext = React.createContext();

export default function App() {
  const [cityList, setCityList]=useState(["city1","city2","city3"]);
    
  const addCityToList = React.useCallback((cityName) => {
      setCityList((oldCityList)=>{return([...oldCityList,cityName])})
  }, [setCityList])

  return (
    <CityContext.Provider value={{cityList, addCityToList}}>
       <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Tab.Screen 
            name="Home" 
            component={HomeScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen 
            name="Settings" 
            component={UserSettings} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </CityContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Then, use it as follows.

```js
const UserSettings = (props) => {
    const { cityList, addCityToList } = React.useContext(CityContext);

    ...

    return (...)
}
```

Then, in `HomeScreen` react on state changes.

```js
const HomeScreen = (props) => {
    const { cityList, addCityToList } = React.useContext(CityContext);
    
    // if you want to do something different, you could do it here
    useEffect(() => {
        // this is triggered, when the state cityList is updated
    }, [cityList])

   return (...)
}
```

**Remarks:** The `useEffect` which I have added above is optional. The state `cityList` is updated nevertheless, and if you just want to render the updated cities, then you do not have to do anything more.

Comment: Thank you! I added this to my code and it almost works. I have an error : Require cycle (app -> HomeScreen -> App) but i'm not sure if it's related. Another remark, in the useCallBack you add [setCityList] to trigger the function call, is it in case i use my own hook and i change the function?

Comment: Glad it worked out! I actually don't know this error message. This looks like a different problem to me. You can name the setter of a state, in this case I named it `setCityList`, to whatever you prefer. It is not really correct saying `you add [setCityList] to trigger the function call`. We use `useCallback` to make a function stable. The dependency array must contain everything that is used inside the function wrapped inside useCallback. In this case it is `setCityList`. This function is itself stable. Thus the function `addCityToList` is only built once.

Comment: If you do not wrap the function inside a `useCallback` it will be recreated in every render cycle. I wanted to prevent that.

Comment: I think the require cycle was due to the context, so i moved the declaration `export const CityContext = React.createContext();` in a separate file and it works now